# right left continuity of $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ at $0$

Tags: real-analysis

> Determine whether $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ is continuous or discontinuous from the right or left at $x_0=0$

We have an asymptote at $x=0$, with $D_f=(-\infty,0) \cup (0,\infty)$.

It follows that an equality between $f(0^-)$ and $f(0)$ is not possible. Likewise, with $f(0^+)$ and $f(0)$.

Therefore, it is discontinuous at $x_0=0$.

Is the argumentation above correct? Is $f$ said to be "non existing" or "not defined" at $x_0$? 
Much appreciated.

Comment: If $f$ is not defined, you can't think about continuity. For prove (or disprove) the continuity of a function in a point $x_0$ necessary this should be defined at $x_0$. The function $f(x)=\displaystyle\frac{1}{x}$ is continuous in $\mathbb{R}\setminus \{0\}$, but the function $g(x)=f(x)$ if $x\neq 0$ and (for example) $20$ if $x=0$ clearly is discontinuous at $x=0$. Consider the two examples; in this way you will see the difference.

Comment: You can think of the sets $\{1/n : n\in \mathbb{N} \}$, and $\{-1/n : n\in \mathbb{N} \}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}f(x)=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{1}{x}$$

In order for a function to be continuous

$$f(a)=\lim_{x \rightarrow a}f(x)$$

For a limit of a function to exist the left hand limit must be equal to the right hand limit such that they are all equal

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow a}f(x)=\lim_{x \rightarrow a^+}f(x)=\lim_{x \rightarrow a^-}f(x)$$

So we need to prove that

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+}f(x)=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+}\frac{1}{x}$$

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+}\frac{1}{x}=+\infty$$

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^-}f(x)=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^-}\frac{1}{x}$$

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^-}\frac{1}{x}=-\infty$$

This is known as infinite discontinuity!

Since

The function is discontinuous because

$f(0)$ is not defined at all

and

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^-}\frac{1}{x} \neq \lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+}\frac{1}{x}$$

We say that the limit does not exist at $x=0$ because left hand limit does not equal to right hand limit.

Limit at $x=0$ does not exist.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to analyze the limit at all.

Going through the definition of continuity:

A function $f$ is continuous at a point $c$ iff the following $3$ conditions are met:

$1)$ $f(c)$ is defined

You don't need to go any further. $f(0)$ is not defined, therefore, $f$ is not continuous at $0$.